# Copy a single row from worksheet to worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The number of ways to simply copy a row in a worksheet to another worksheet is bewildering, as is the number of parameters required to specify it. Every example I examine is different and I can;t sort them out.

This is what I have:

```
Dim MyCell As Range, fromRange As Range, wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

Set wsFrom = Sheets("Sheet 0")
Set MyRange = wsFrom.Range("C3:C2000")

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then
        If Not sheetExist(MyCell.Value) Then
            Set wsTo = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 'creates a new worksheet
            wsTo.Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
        Else
            Set wsTo = Worksheets(MyCell.Value)
        End If
        
        wsFrom.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Copy wsTo.Range("A" & lastRow)
        
                
    End If
Next MyCell

Function sheetExist(sSheet As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetExist = (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheet).Index > 0)
End Function
```

My rows are only a few columns wide, I only need to copy one at a time and I only need to append it to the bottom of the other sheet. I'll finesse all that later.

I just don't know what I'm supposed to do at the *copy* line. The above code throws a **Method 'Range' of object 'Worksheet' failed** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close to finish.

*Changes:*

- `Option Explicit` is helpful to avoid coding error.
- `lastRow` should be assigned an value before using in `wsTo.Range("A" & lastRow)`
- `wsFrom.Rows(MyCell.Row).EntireRow` is same as `wsFrom.Rows(MyCell.Row)`, `ActiveCell.Row` is different with `MyCell.Row`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRow()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set wsFrom = Sheets("Sheet 0")
    Set MyRange = wsFrom.Range("C3:C2000")
    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then
            If Not sheetExist(MyCell.Value) Then
                Set wsTo = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 'creates a new worksheet
                wsTo.Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
                lastRow = 1
            Else
                Set wsTo = Worksheets(MyCell.Value)
                lastRow = wsTo.Cells(wsTo.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If
            wsFrom.Rows(MyCell.Row).Copy wsTo.Range("A" & lastRow)
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
Function sheetExist(sSheet As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetExist = (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheet).Index > 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. You addressed a number of problems in my code and it worked first time!